# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingHandler

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this following exception while running my program. I am not getting this issue if I downgrade my selenium from 3.12.0 to 2.53.0 but this downgrade impacts other existing working scripts in my code. Hence wish to stick with 3.12.0 and wanted to rectify this exception. Since Logginghander is part of selenium api, have tired by adding it in maven but this produced another similar issue. Need helping hands here.

> Jdk: 8, Jre: 1.8, Selenium-driver: 3.12.0, Chrome driver: 2.40, OS:
>   Windows 10, Eclipse: Neon, Browser version: 67.0.3396.87

**Method:- (Where error is pointed out)** -

```
public class StepsDefinitionFileofUI {

    @Before(value = "@Initilization", order = 1)
    public static void driver() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty((ReadProperties.GetConfig("ChromeDriver")), (ReadProperties.GetConfig("ChromeDriverPath")));
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); ***<== Error pointing out this line***
        GlobalVariable.setDriver(driver);
        SessionId session = ((ChromeDriver) GlobalVariable.getDriver()).getSessionId();
        GlobalVariable.getLog().info("");
        GlobalVariable.getLog().info("***** The Session id is : " + session.toString() + " *****");
        GlobalVariable.getLog().info("");
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        GlobalVariable.getLog().info("***** The Selected Driver is Chrome ******");
    }
```

**Complete Exception:-**

```
Failure in before hook:StepsDefinitionFileofUI.driver()
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/logging/LoggingHandler
    at UserInterfaceTesting.StepsDefinitionFileofUI.driver(StepsDefinitionFileofUI.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
    at cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.feature(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.logging.LoggingHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

**POM File:-**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>CollectingArts</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceTesting</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ServiceTesting</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.72</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/smtp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- TESTNG -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.qatools.ashot/ashot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
            <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-safari-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SELENIUM-JAVA -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- REST ASSURED -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTPCLIENT -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- APACHE POI -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.logstash.log4j/jsonevent-layout -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonevent-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- JSON SCHEMA VALIDATOR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- /// Cucumber Area /// -->


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vimalselvam/cucumber-extentsreport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports 
            <dependency> <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId> <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId> 
            <version>2.41.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Cucumber-Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- json Object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20171018</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.openkeyword/autoit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.openkeyword</groupId>
            <artifactId>autoit</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: what is your browser version ?

Comment: Selenium 3.12.0 Supports Chrome v66-68 , please check and update us.

Comment: My browser version is: 67.0.3396.87

Comment: Issue was due to multiple versions of 'selenium java' in Maven. I had figured out later after removing the duplicates. Thanks for all your assistance!!!